# In gradle, how can I run a task against all projects recursively from command line?

Tags: gradle

I'm looking for a syntax along the lines of `./gradlew :all:myTask` that I can quickly execute from the command line.  I must have missed it in the documentation somewhere.

I know I can modify the build to include a new task that runs a task against all sub-projects, however I'd prefer to not mess with modifying the build for simple one-off scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your goal correctly, running `./gradlew myTask` should do what you want by default

```
:myTask
:foo:myTask
:foo:bar:myTask
:baz:myTask
```

Comment: Note, works normally, but not for some tasks, eg `dependencies`.  Turns out in my case, something unrelated was causing the build to trip over itself with the new task I had given it.  Namely, making `build` depend on `someTask` which then `dependsOn clean` ...